# Cannot Eager Load Entity Framework Child Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have implemented a UnitOfWork style method of working and I cannot seem to force an eager load in EntityFramework 6. Every time I use the "Include()" syntax it seems to be ignored and the SQL generated will not carry out any form of join which is resulting in a very large amount of SQL being generated as each child entity is having to be queried in the database by its ID.

This is my setup:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly SimpleStorageEntities _simpleStorageEntities;

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        _simpleStorageEntities = new SimpleStorageEntities();
    }

    public List<T> Query<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] loadOptions) where T : class
    {
        var set = _simpleStorageEntities.Set<T>();

        if (loadOptions.Any())
        {
            foreach (var expression in loadOptions)
            {
                set.Include(expression);
            }
        }
        return set.Where(predicate).ToList();
    }
}
```

My invocation is as follows:

```
var entries = _unitOfWork.Query<Entry>(e => e.TableId == tableId,
            e => e.AttributeValues);
```

Even though I have specified that I want the AttributeValues loaded, each time one is accessed through a foreach a database call is made. I tried to explicitly specify the Includes in the constructor of the UnitOfWork however this seemingly didn't make any difference.

EDIT: Checked through previous versions on EF just to ensure it isn't version related, no luck

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue with the code above. It is within the foreach of the loadOptions.

This:

```
set.Include(expression);
```

Should actually be:

```
set = set.Include(expression);
```

Otherwise the Include is simply ignored as it isn't being written back to the set to be executed.